# Wrong GPU used for blender?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

When working with e.g. Blender my computer gets super slow and it seems my GPU is topping out. Is it possible that the system is using the wrong GPU (Intel Graphics) rather than NVidia for certain tasks?

[image]

```
Dell XPS 15 (2018)
Geforce GTX 1050
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz
Installed RAM   16,0 GB (15,9 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎29.‎11.‎2020
```

Comment: In User preferences -> System -> Compute device, you can configure which Cuda devices to use

Comment: sorry, could you dumb this down a little for me :)? Do you mean the option Compute device exists somewhere in the control panel?

Comment: I tried messing around a bit in the device manager but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the Blender application itself.

Answer (score 1):

With Blender, this is done within the application itself.

1. You want to open the `Edit` menu item and scroll to the very bottom where you will find `Preferences`
2. Within the dialog that appears, select `System` (which is probably already up as it is the default).
3. At the top of this dialog, you will see selections for `Cycles Render Device`.  You are probably going to want to play with the `Cuda` settings but `OptiX` might be better depending on what your machine can support.

Specific Documentation for the GPU settings can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html).

Good Luck!